# Twig PHP Template Engine Class 'Twig_Loader_String' not found

Tags: php, twig

Am Trying To use the twig template engine , i included the "Autoload" file from the lib folder as bellow :

```
require_once 'lib/Twig-1.15.0/Twig-1.15.0/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('Hello {{ name }}!', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

And after i start the server i keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_String' not found in C:\wamp\www\school_library\index.php on line 12
```

I am using Wamp Server , What do you think is the problem ? and is the File "/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php" the right one to require ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Are you using `composer`?

Comment: am trying to use the "Basic API Usage" from http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html#installation , and what is the deference between using a composer and not using a composer ?

Comment: Read about [composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md). Go to the last section of your link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using **Composer** I suggest you go read [this install page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html) so that you may actually have **Twig** on your server. I sometimes use the tarball and unpack it in a directory of my project, yet I think you should try out **Composer**, it seems like a very nifty tool to handle this exact situation